# How to check the first 2 characters ( case-insensitive ) in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a search input box.

[image]

I already check for the first 2 characters.

`$first_two = substr($search,0,2);`

They need to start with **BS**, so I check them like this :

```
if ($search AND $first_two == 'bs' ){
 // ... do stuffs
}
```

After that, I just realize that I don't want to have any restriction on them.

I want my first two character is **case-insensitive**.

I want to allow `BS`, `Bs`, `bs` and `bS`.

What do I need to fix in my `if (?)` to allow these to happens ?

Comment: Convert the search string to lower case before you search: 
string strtolower ( string $str )

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky : got it ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a certain case for your comparison, this example uses lower case

```
$first_two = substr($search,0,2); 
if ($search AND strtolower($first_two) == 'bs' ){
 // ... do stuffs
}
```

This way `BS`, `Bs`, `bS` will all be converted to `bs` and your comparison will always work

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) like this:

```
if ($search AND strcasecmp($first_two , "bs") == 0)
              //^If both strings are the same (case-insensitive) the function returns 0
```

Comment: Yea No well known reason for a down-vote really. This answer is correct.

Comment: I completely agree. Downvotes should explain why, instead of leaving the person guessing till the cows come home. Plus, what if the person doesn't have any cows; what then? Wait forever? ;-) Many cows have bells to help us find them when they're lost or ran astray, what if you don't hear the bells? *Ah!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I liked your expression with cow.

Comment: @iori I like to add some humour for situations like these. Just so we don't get anyone angry. Laughing is so much more agreeable ;-)